# Does OpenCV installed by conda can be used with C++? And how?

Tags: c++, opencv, build, cmake, conda

I use conda install OpenCV use:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

I can use OpenCV with python with no error.

Since conda is a convenience tool to build OpenCV, I am wondering whether I can use OpenCV installed by conda with C++.

And how to use it?

---

I have `opencv.hpp` in `/home/kandy/miniconda3/include/boost/compute/interop`, and here it's what the folder contains:

```
.
├── eigen
│   └── core.hpp
├── eigen.hpp
├── opencv
│   ├── core.hpp
│   ├── highgui.hpp
│   └── ocl.hpp
├── opencv.hpp
├── opengl
│   ├── acquire.hpp
│   ├── cl_gl_ext.hpp
│   ├── cl_gl.hpp
│   ├── context.hpp
│   ├── gl.hpp
│   ├── opengl_buffer.hpp
│   ├── opengl_renderbuffer.hpp
│   └── opengl_texture.hpp
├── opengl.hpp
├── qt
│   ├── qimage.hpp
│   ├── qpointf.hpp
│   ├── qpoint.hpp
│   ├── qtcore.hpp
│   ├── qtgui.hpp
│   └── qvector.hpp
├── qt.hpp
├── vtk
│   ├── bounds.hpp
│   ├── data_array.hpp
│   ├── matrix4x4.hpp
│   └── points.hpp
└── vtk.hpp
```

Comment: Does it contain the headers and libs?

Comment: I have added some information to my question.

Comment: That doesn't look like all headers.